# How do I scroll left or right in a text input field on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

Sometimes webpages are completely nonfunctional on a phone. There's no way to edit text that extends beyond the text box.

[image]

Comment: Hold down your finger to bring up the magnifying glass. Drag it in the direction you want to scroll through the text

Comment: @Sambuu That doesn't work. You can see I'm already at the right edge, and it won't scroll.

Comment: I've occasionally experienced this same thing. I'm not 100% sure, but I think I've been able to get around it by selecting like a single word in the visible area and then extending that to the end using one of the handles (which can also be buggy sometimes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an iPhone with Force Touch you can force press down anywhere on the keyboard to bring up the typing cursor. If you drag your finger to the right/left side of the display(without letting go) the text will scroll in that direction.

Not 100% on how you would do this on an iPhone 6 or older as it has been a long time since I have used one. You might still be able to hold down on the keyboard..?

Comment: Sorry I updated the answer to add the tag iPhone 5.

Comment: If your device doesn't have 3D touch you can do the same by pressing and holding on the space-bar until the cursor comes up.

Comment: @LaterSkater Sorry iPhone 5 has iOS 10.3.3 - no space-bar-cursor.

Comment: I did get an iPhone 8+ so I'll take this for now until an answer for the original situation appears.